# Output formatted data from groups efficiently and succinctly

Tags: r

I've taken to using R for much more than I likely should because my brain is now becoming vectorized. My current use case results in a grouped dataframe via a series of operations leveraging `dplyr`. I'd like to efficiently create a structured text output with minimal use of loops (I've already accomplished my end goal with a series of nested loops).

As an example:

```
set.seed(1)
data.frame(replicate(5,sample(letters[1:3],20,rep=TRUE))) %>% 
    group_by(X1,X2) %>% 
    summarise()
```

Results in:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
Groups: X1

  X1 X2
1  a  a
2  a  b
3  a  c
4  b  a
5  b  b
6  b  c
7  c  a
8  c  b
9  c  c
```

I'd like to create an output from each of the levels of group like this:

```
+ a
++ a
++ b
++ c
+ b
++ a
++ b
```

and so on...

Right now, I'm embarrassed to share I'm doing it with a loop over X1 as a factor with an inner loop of X2 as a factor. I'm ultimately trying to dynamically create a configuration file for a broader application but this simple df highlights the essence. I imagine there is a creative restructuring of the `group_by()` and some use of `do()` to to resolve this but I'm struggling.

Comment: Is that exactly the type of output you want (with all of the `+` signs and all)? `split` would already do the separation for you.

Comment: Yes, the real output is actually a bit more complex, with various adjustments of formatting of X1 and X2 -- and there is actually a third grouping variable in the real case. I'm attempting to build the section under target configuration at: http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/doc/smokeping_examples.en.html#___top from the results of numerous manipulations of various JSON sources. I really am sticking to this path to improve my understanding of working with grouped dataframes.

Comment: Maybe my brain is not vectorized enough, but I don't see the link between the `dplyr` output and your expected output with the `+` signs. Could you explain that?

Comment: There isn't a direct link between the `dplyr` output and my desired output. I guess my thought is if I understood how to work with the grouped_df better, I could generate my required output without incrementing through a series of nested loops. The `+` signs can be generated via a function that `cat`s the appropriate pieces perhaps via a `do()`.